# Euler-Lagrange equations using tensor calculus

Tags: mathematical-physics, tensors

Let $B_{\mu\nu}(\vec{x})$ be a symmetric and invertible tensor and let $\mathcal{L}$ be the following *scalar* function:

$$\mathcal{L}=-\left(\frac{dT}{d\lambda}\right)^{-1}B_{\mu\nu}(\vec{x})\frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\lambda}$$

Where the parameter $T$ is defined as:

$$T=\int dT,\quad dT^2=B_{\mu\nu}(\vec{x})dx^\mu dx^\nu$$

Note that Einstein's Summation Convention is used - both $\mu,\nu$ are summed from $0$ up to some natural number $n\in\mathbb{N}$. I am required to show that the following $n$ equations (*Euler-Lagrange* equations):

$$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial{x^\sigma}}=\frac{d}{d\lambda}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\dot{x}^\sigma},\quad\quad \dot{x}^\sigma\triangleq \frac{dx^\sigma}{d\lambda},\sigma=0,1,2,...,n$$

Can be translated to the following $n$ equations:

$$\frac{d^2x^\alpha}{dT^2}=\Omega_{\ \ \mu\nu}^{\alpha}\frac{dx^\mu}{dT}\frac{dx^\nu}{dT}$$

Where $\Omega$ depends on the tensor $B$ but does **not** depend on $\lambda$.

---

Fortunately, I am not frightened of the indices. However, I have no idea how to handle $dT/d\lambda$. For instance - does it depend on $x$? This is crucial in order to find the left hand side of the Euler-Lagrange equations. Additionally, even if I knew the answer to that question - how can I express that derivative? As much as it hurt, I tried to do the following:

$$\left(\frac{dT}{d\lambda}\right)^{-1}=\left[\left(\frac{dT}{d\lambda}\right)^2\right]^{-1/2}=\left[B_{\mu\nu}(\vec{x})\frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\lambda}\right]^{-1/2}$$

But I have no idea if this is correct. The final answer should be:

$$\Omega_{\ \ \mu\nu}^{\alpha}=\frac 12(B^{-1})^{\alpha\sigma}\left(2\frac{\partial B_{\mu\nu}}{\partial x^\sigma}-\frac{\partial B_{\sigma\nu}}{\partial x^\mu}-\frac{\partial B_{\mu\sigma}}{\partial x^\nu}\right)$$

No matter what I tried (and I tried **a lot** of things) I couldn't get to that answer.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I got a few questions. Since $B_{\mu v}$ depends on $x$, what type of tensor is this? Because I think that might matter when you take the derivative w.r.t to $x^\sigma$ for one your Lagrangian derivatives.

Comment: @IAmNoOne I have no idea actually. It is indeed weird. I am not so familiar with tensors, they are rather new to me. I of course wrote the question exactly as I received it.

Comment: I did some research - the components of $\Omega$ seem like Christoffel Symbols (general relativity), so in accordance, $B$ might be some sort of a metric tensor, although I'm not sure

Comment: Is this from a reference? Which page?

Comment: if you are not afraid of indexing, you should be studying the case where the technique is illustrated in the case of geodesic curves on a surface. A good book on that could be Vector Analysis of Murray Spiegel + Seymour Lipschutz

Comment: This looks very much like the calculation of the Euler Lagrange equations for a single particle (say mass $1$) moving in a Riemannian manifold, with metric tensor $g$. What you've written as $B_{\mu \nu}$ is typically written as $g_{\mu \nu}$, and your $\Omega^{\alpha}_{\mu \nu}$ is typically $-\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\mu \nu}$. Also, I think in your definition of $\Omega$, you have an extra $2$; pretty sure it should just be $\Omega = \dfrac{1}{2}(B^{-1}) \left( \dfrac{\partial B}{\partial x} -  \dfrac{\partial B}{\partial x} -  \dfrac{\partial B}{\partial x}\right)$ (with appropriate indices)

Comment: @peek-a-boo The $\Omega$ you have written is the known Christoffel Symbol, and it would have been the answer if the lagrangian $\mathcal{L}$ hadn't had the $dT/d\lambda$ part in it. I checked the answers again and unfortunately, the $2$ isn't extra and should be there (unless the answers are wrong, of course)

Comment: Can you answer Qmechanic? What is the reference?

Comment: @IAmNoOne I am studying Electrodynamics and this question was presented to me in a book of questions that our lecturer created. It's not an official book, just a bunch of questions with final answers

Answer (score 1):

1. Define a Lagrangian $${\cal L}_0~:=~ B_{\mu\nu}(x)\frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\lambda}~=:~\left(\frac{dT}{d\lambda}\right)^2,\tag{A}$$
   where $B_{\mu\nu}$ are components of a pseudo-Riemannian metric tensor with [Levi-Civita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection) [Christoffel symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols) $-\Omega^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu}$, cf. above comment by user peek-a-boo. We will assume that the velocity vector of a virtual path has non-negative norm-square.
2. OP's Lagrangian becomes minus the square root: 
   $${\cal L}~:=~-\left(\frac{dT}{d\lambda}\right)^{-1}{\cal L}_0~=~-\frac{dT}{d\lambda}~=~-\sqrt{{\cal L}_0}.\tag{B}$$
   The corresponding functional $$T~=~-\int \! d\lambda~{\cal L}\tag{C}$$ is just the [arc-length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length). Hence the stationary paths are all [geodesics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic) (in the sense that they satisfy the geodesic equation) and with arbitrary parametrization. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149082/2451) related Phys.SE post.